# Why is connectivity test for PostgreSQL undetermined?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP. I created SQL instance,but connectivity test failed.

why?

```
after the rerun
Aborted because no valid source endpoint is derived from the input test request
```

hmm,what is valid and what is unvalid source point?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an [Undetermined](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/support/troubleshooting#undetermined-state) result is because configuration analysis could not determine connectivity, and could be caused by the following:

- Lack of permission on the resource you are trying to read
- Internal error occured
- The analyzer received an invalid or unsupported argument or was unable to identify a known endpoint
- You are trying to verify a route that extends beyond Google Cloud. Connectivity Tests has no access to network configurations outside Google Cloud.

Check Cloud SQL's [Manage connectivity tests](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/manage-connectivity-tests) to make sure that you configured your [connectivity test](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/concepts/overview) correctly.